# What is the ReactiveUI way to handle exceptions when executing inferior ReactiveCommands?

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

Here is a (over) simplified version of what I am trying to demonstrate:

```
var reactiveCommandA = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(_ => CanPossiblyThrowAsync());
reactiveCommandA.ThrownExceptions
                .Subscribe(ex => UserError.Throw("Oh no A", ex));

var reactiveCommandB = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(_ => CanAlsoPossiblyThrowAsync());
reactiveCommandB.ThrownExceptions
                .Subscribe(ex => UserError.Throw("Oh no B", ex));

var reactiveCommandC = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask
   (
     async _ =>
               {
                 await reactiveCommandA.ExecuteAsync(); // <= Could throw here
                 await reactiveCommandB.ExecuteAsync();
                 DoSomethingElse();
               }
    );

reactiveCommandC.ThrownExceptions
                .Subscribe(ex => UserError.Throw("Oh no C", ex));
```

So assume my background implementation for `reactiveCommandA` might throw an exception.  That is OK, since I have subscribed to `.ThrownExceptions` and will theoretically notify the user and retry/fail/abort (not shown here for brevity).  So it will not bubble up to the dispatcher.

So that is great when `reactiveCommandA` is executed by itself.  However, I have `reactiveCommandC` which executes `reactiveCommandA` and `reactiveCommandB`.  I also subscribe to its `.ThrownExceptions`.  The problem I'm running into is that if I execute `reactiveCommandC` and `reactiveCommandA` implementation throws within it, it also causes `reactiveCommandC` to blow up.  Then I'm notifying the user twice for the same root error becuase `reactiveCommandA` does its `.ThrownExceptions` thing, then `reactiveCommandC` does its `.ThrownExceptions` thing.

So is there a standard approach to this type of situation?  Preferably something somewhat elegant, since I find the existing code fairly clean and I don't want to clutter things up or introduce spaghetti.

Things I have thought of:

- Surrounding the "await..." line with `try/catch` block and swallowing exception and exiting.  Seems ugly if I have to do it a lot.
- Using `await reactiveCommandA.ExecuteAsync().Catch(Observable.Never<Unit>());` although I think this will cause reactiveCommandC to never complete so it can never execute again.
- Using the same approach with the `.Catch()` method but returning a boolean based on whether I made it through successfully or not (e.g. `.Catch(Observable.Return(false))`.  Would still have to check if we could continue between each `await` statement.

Is there something slicker to do here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm, this is an aspect of the ReactiveCommand design that kind of sucks (disclosure: I can say it sucks, I wrote it!)  Here's the lazy way of fixing it:

```
Observable.Merge(rxCmdA.ThrownExceptions, rxCmdB.ThrownExceptions, rxCmdC.ThrownExceptions)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .Subscribe(ex => UserError.Throw("Oh no C", ex));
```

In the future I definitely want to fix some of these kind of double-throwing things, as well as a few other things about the RxCmd design.

Comment: Fair enough, Paul.  While not a super-satisfying answer, I am glad that it is on your radar for future improvements, and I'm also happy to know that I wasn't missing something obvious.  I will continue to see how RxUI continues to evolve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but how about something like this?

```
bool shouldThrow = true;

var reactiveCommandA = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(_ => CanPossiblyThrowAsync());
reactiveCommandA.ThrownExceptions
                .Where(_ => shouldThrow)
                .Subscribe(ex => UserError.Throw("Oh no A", ex));

var reactiveCommandB = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(_ => CanAlsoPossiblyThrowAsync());
reactiveCommandB.ThrownExceptions
                .Where(_ => shouldThrow)
                .Subscribe(ex => UserError.Throw("Oh no B", ex));

var reactiveCommandC = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask
   (
     async _ =>
               {
                 shouldThrow = false;

                 try
                 {
                     await reactiveCommandA.ExecuteAsync(); // <= Could throw here
                     await reactiveCommandB.ExecuteAsync();
                 }

                 finally
                 {
                     shouldThrow = true;
                 }
                 DoSomethingElse();
               }
    );

reactiveCommandC.ThrownExceptions
                .Subscribe(ex => UserError.Throw("Oh no C", ex));
```

Maybe not super elegant, but it should work in theory

Comment: Thanks, I thought of something similar too, even though now it is a flag I need to remember to set.  It might be a fix in simple scenarios like the example, but becomes unwieldy if I have a lot of intertwined commands.